# CS50 (pset2) - Behavior not understood in C program that prints out initials

Tags: c, cs50

I have prior experience with Python but absolute beginner in C. I am working on *CS50x pset2 initials (less comfortable)*, where a simple C program is supposed to **accept a name given by the user and the print out its initials of the name**.

When I run the program, it seems to work for some situations, but for some names it is appending a wrong 'B' char at the end. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

string get_initials(string name, char initials[]);

int main(void)
{
    // user input (full name)
    printf("Please type your name: ");
    string name = get_string();

    // get the user name initials
    char initials[10];
    get_initials(name, initials);  // in: full name; out: initials
    printf("Initials: %s\n", initials);

}

string get_initials(string name, char initials[])
{
    int counter = 0;

    // Iterate over all characters
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(name); i < n; i++)
    {
        // in case the i-th char is ' ', appends next char to the initials array
        if (name[i] == ' ')
        {
            initials[counter] = name[i+1];
            counter++;
        }
        // appends the first char to the initials array
        else if (i == 0)
        {
            initials[counter] = name[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return initials;
}
```

And here are some Terminal outputs:

```
~/workspace/pset2/ $ ./initials
Please type your name: John Smith
Initials: JSB
~/workspace/pset2/ $ ./initials
Please type your name: John Smith Here
Initials: JSH
~/workspace/pset2/ $ ./initials
Please type your name: John
Initials: J
~/workspace/pset2/ $ ./initials
Please type your name: John Smith Here Again
Initials: JSHAB
~/workspace/pset2/ $ ./initials
Please type your name: John Smith Here Again Where
Initials: JSHAW
~/workspace/pset2/ $ ./initials
Please type your name: John Smith Here Again Where Here
Initials: JSHAWH
~/workspace/pset2/ $
```

I [debugged for "John Smith"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmbBc.png) but still can't understand why it is appending **S\320\330B** instead of just **S**.

Comment: You get this because CS-50 fails completely to teach how strings work in the C language. All strings must be null terminated. You don't null terminate the initials string properly. The solution is to get a better source of learning.

Comment: No `string` data type in C.

Comment: @haccks There is one in the CS-50 course. They did `typedef char* string` as part of the cs50.h library they teach beginners with. Yes, the people who designed this crappy course were really that stupid.

Comment: @Lundin; *the people who designed this crappy course were really that stupid*: Can't agree more.

Comment: `counter++;` --> `counter++;initials[counter] = 0;`

Comment: A C-"string" is just a `char`-array carrying a `'\0'`-character to mark the end of the string. `initials`doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! just inserted a `initials[counter] = '\0';` in the end of the function and it worked

Comment: If to lazy to keep track of the string's end, an alternative, slightly inefficient approach is to initialised the `char`-array to all `0`s: `char initials[10] = "";` (which is the same as `memset(initials, 0, 10);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the `get_initials` function, terminate the string:

```
...
initials[counter] = '\0';
return initials;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! just inserted a `initials[counter] = '\0';` in the end of the function and it worked fine!